# How to use Matplotlib's animate function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

Can anyone see what exactly is wrong with my code here? I am trying to generate an animated plot of my results to see its evolution over time and the result is just a full plot of my data, rather than an updating animation.

[image]

The `sampleText.txt` file is just a numpy array of size `(5000, 1)`, The first 5 entries of the array are `[[-0.01955058],[ 0.00658392[,[-0.00658371],[-0.0061325 ],[-0.0219136 ]]`

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot()

def animate(i):
    
    x = np.linspace(0, len(dataArray), len(dataArray))
    y = []

    for eachLine in x:
        y.append(eachLine * 10)
            
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(x, y, color = 'red', alpha = 0.5)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func = animate)

plt.show()
```

Comment: So what's the problem? You have half a question and half of a [MCVE] here

Comment: @MadPhysicist Please see my updates to the question. I have simplified the example and showed the issue more clearly. I get a plot outright of the entire data, rather than an animation of the updates which is what I want

Comment: Thanks for staying responsive. Could you provide a data sample. Like a call to `np.arange` or `np.random`, instead of just a verbal description?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean but my this is an example of what the first 5 entries to my '(5000,1)' numpy array looks like '[[-0.01955058]
 [ 0.00658392]
 [-0.00658371]
 [-0.0061325 ]
 [-0.0219136 ]]'

Comment: You don't need the exact array. Just provide some code that generates something similar. See [MCVE] for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis of animation is a mechanism where the animation function sets the values to be changed for the initial graph setting. In this case, the line width is 3, the color is red, and x and y are an empty list. xy data is linked to the number of frames by i in the animation function.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation 

fig = plt.figure() 

# marking the x-axis and y-axis 
axis = plt.axes(xlim =(0, 500), ylim =(0, 1000)) 

x = np.linspace(0, 500, 500) 
y = x*2
# initializing a line variable 
line, = axis.plot([], [], lw=2, color='r') 

def animate(i): 
    line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i]) 
    return line, 

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=500, blit=True, repeat=False) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please refer to the basics in the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-simple-anim-py). If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer

Comment: I will check this for my work and let you know. Thanks for the response.